# HInternet works only one time

Tags: c++, wcf

This code is in a C++ DLL injected in a game. (This is on a private server so it is legal). The code has to be executed multiple times. However, it works only the first time. It could be on the WCF end but I  managed to send 2 and 5 successful requests from a .net dll loaded from the c++ dll before.

Since I didn't figure out why it was blocked after 2 and 5 requests, I decided to go all native but now I'm blocked after one request. I have a feeling it now has to do with the way I'm parsing the response.

The first execution gets a 200 code status and the second one gets a 0.

edit : my fire wall is turned off.

```
HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(_T("MyApp"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hInternet, _T("localhost"), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

LPCSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = { _T("application/json"), NULL };

HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, _T("POST"), _T("/xxxBackend/service1.svc/SaveDataVoid"), NULL, NULL, rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, 0);

HttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest, _T("Content-Type: application/json\r\n"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);

char *JsonData = "{\"data\":{\"AccountName\":\"\",\"CharName\":\"SilverDeth-IV\",\"GameDiff\":\"1\",\"CompressedData\":[8228138568842941382,8247906688399250381,8244242016143283142]}}";
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, NULL, 0, JsonData, strlen(JsonData));

DWORD StatusCode = 0;
DWORD StatusCodeLen = sizeof(StatusCode);
HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, &StatusCode, &StatusCodeLen, NULL);

if (StatusCode == 200)
{
    char *lpBuffer[2000];
    DWORD lpdwNumberOfBytesRead = 0;

    InternetQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &StatusCodeLen, 0, 0);
    bool bRetval = InternetReadFile(hRequest, lpBuffer, 2000, &lpdwNumberOfBytesRead);


}

InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
```

Comment: Being on a private server doesn't automatically make everything legal.

Comment: Yea. I have admin approval. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown is not doing ANY error handling at all.  Add that in, and then see where the failure is really occurring. The fact that `StatusCode` is 0 means `HttpQueryInfo()` is failing, which could happen if you did not obtain a valid `hRequest` to begin with.

BTW, `rgpszAcceptTypes` needs to be declared as `LPCTSTR` instead of `LPCSTR`, and you should be using the `TEXT()` macro instead of the `_T()` macro. `TEXT()` belongs to the Win32 API, but `_T()` belongs to the C runtime library, which you are not using in this code.

Try this:

```
void InetError(LPCTSTR msg)
{
    DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
    if (dwErr == ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR)
    {
        DWORD dwInetErr = 0;
        LPTSTR szResp = NULL;
        DWORD dwLength = 0;

        InternetGetLastResponseInfo(&dwInetErr, NULL, &dwLength);
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            szResp = new TCHAR[dwLength+1];
            InternetGetLastResponseInfo(&dwInetErr, szResp, &dwLength);
        }

        // use msg, szResp, and dwInetErr as needed...
        delete[] szResp;
    }
    else
    {
        // use msg and dwErr as needed...
    }
}

...

HINTERNET hInternet = NULL;
HINTERNET hConnect = NULL;
HINTERNET hRequest = NULL;

hInternet = InternetOpen(TEXT("MyApp"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (!hInternet)
{
    InetError(TEXT("InternetOpen failed"));
    goto done;
}

hConnect = InternetConnect(hInternet, TEXT("localhost"), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
if (!hConnect)
{
    InetError(TEXT("InternetConnect failed"));
    goto done;
}

LPCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = { TEXT("application/json"), NULL };

hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, TEXT("POST"), TEXT("/xxxBackend/service1.svc/SaveDataVoid"), NULL, NULL, rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, 0);
if (!hRequest)
{
    InetError(TEXT("HttpOpenRequest failed"));
    goto done;
}

if (!HttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest, TEXT("Content-Type: application/json\r\n"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD))
{
    InetError(TEXT("HttpAddRequestHeaders failed"));
    goto done;
}

char *JsonData = "{\"data\":{\"AccountName\":\"\",\"CharName\":\"SilverDeth-IV\",\"GameDiff\":\"1\",\"CompressedData\":[8228138568842941382,8247906688399250381,8244242016143283142]}}";
if (!HttpSendRequest(hRequest, NULL, 0, JsonData, strlen(JsonData)))
{
    InetError(TEXT("HttpSendRequest failed"));
    goto done;
}

DWORD StatusCode = 0;
DWORD StatusCodeLen = sizeof(StatusCode);
if (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, &StatusCode, &StatusCodeLen, NULL))
{
    InetError(TEXT("HttpQueryInfo failed"));
    goto done;
}

if (StatusCode == 200)
{
    BYTE Buffer[2000];
DWORD dwNumberOfBytes = 0;
DWORD dwNumberOfBytesRead = 0;

if (!InternetQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwNumberOfBytes, 0, 0))
    {
        InetError(TEXT("InternetQueryDataAvailable failed"));
        goto done;
    }

if (!InternetReadFile(hRequest, Buffer, min(dwNumberOfBytes, sizeof(Buffer)), &dwNumberOfBytesRead))
    {
        InetError(TEXT("InternetReadFile failed"));
        goto done;
    }

    //...
}

done:
if (hRequest) InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
if (hConnect) InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
if (hInternet) InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
```

Comment: Thanks, Remy. Still works for one call only. HttpSendRequest throws a 12029 error on the second call. Apparantly that could be caused by many things. In my case the problem might be iis or the wcf serivce configuration...

Comment: Changed the WCF service for a MVC Controller. Same thing. Works one time.